Restore a BTRFS drive's root tree that was erroneously overwritten with 100MB FAT storage
I have a 4TB drive with a BTRFS filesystem on it (no partition) that was erroneously overwritten by Windows' installer which determined that the space was unused and that it would use it for some other purpose (Recovery?) and put a 100MB FAT partition on top of it.
Short of it is that all of the content of the drive is currently inaccessible. For the most part, a lot of my really critical files have backups on my home server so the damage isn't extraordinarily overwhelming, but there are always a few rogue files that are missed in the backup that you only figure out when you look to back up. As a result, I've been looking for some way to either restore the file system or perhaps browse whatever contents are still sitting around on the disk.
So far, I've done the following:
I've run btrfs rescue super-recover which outputs the following:
$ sudo btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/sda
All Devices:
    Device: id = 1, name = /dev/sda

Before Recovering:
    [All good supers]:
        device name = /dev/sda
        superblock bytenr = 65536

        device name = /dev/sda
        superblock bytenr = 274877906944

    [All bad supers]:
        device name = /dev/sda
        superblock bytenr = 67108864
Make sure this is a btrfs disk otherwise the tool will destroy other fs, Are you sure? [y/N]: y
checksum verify failed on 25001984 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 25001984 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
ERROR: cannot read chunk root
Failed to recover bad superblocks

I also attempted to run sudo btrfs rescue chunk-recover but the result was also similar: It couldn't find a valid tree root.
Next, using the IDs above, I tried to restore the disk to a file location:
$ sudo btrfs restore -t 78515 -u 1 /dev/sda /tmp/a
No valid Btrfs found on /dev/sda
Could not open root, trying backup super
checksum verify failed on 25001984 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 25001984 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 25001984 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 25001984, bytenr mismatch, want=25001984, have=0
ERROR: cannot read chunk root
Could not open root, trying backup super

Similar problem: There's no longer a valid root due to that 100MB FAT!
Lastly, I know of the option of browsing files with testdisk but it doesn't seem like I can browse all remaining files from a BTRFS filesystem: The only option is to clone an image of the disk.
Does anyone have any potential solution for browsing individual files on a invalid BTRFS filesystem or perhaps partially recreate the root? I don't need to restore the whole file system really, ideally I'd be able to get as many files from a subvolume (for example @pictures) that are still "valid" enough to be a real file. Is there a way to recreate the root tree of the BTRFS filesystem to try to recover as many files on the disk?
I can see a table of file names when I do sudo strings /dev/sda | less which seems to imply that I might be able to find some data associated with those files further down the disk, but I have no clue how to check that.

I don't know anything about how btrfs specifically stores data on the disk, however I do know that other filesystems like ext[2-4] tend to put the metadata (like inodes) at the front of the disk, and if btrfs is the same, then overwriting the first 100 MB might have wiped most or all of that metadata.
That said, if it only created a 100 MB filesystem and didn't populate it, it might have only overwritten part of that 100 MB, so most of the metadata might have survived.  Maybe.
Somebody more familiar with btrfs would be better able to help with the path you're on.
However, there is another possible path, one that doesn't involve detailed knowledge of the filesystem's structure: looking for known signatures of data.
There is a tool called "photorec" that will scan a disk image and look for known file formats and whatever it finds will be copied off.  It was originally written to recover jpegs from SD cards, but it has since been extended to cover many known file formats.
So if what you're doing doesn't give you any results, you might try photorec.

I think that it didn't populate the folder much at all, after checking by mounting the lone FAT drive.
I will consider photorec as that sounds like a decent option.
